# Multiple GraphQL entities in root mutations/queries?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-tools

How to add multiple queries/mutations from different entities to graphql schema?

I have file called User.graphql and defined schema:

```
import UserQueries, UserMutations from 'User.graphql'

schema {
  query: UserQueries,
  mutation: UserMutations
}
```

and it works. Now I would like to add another entity called Event and related Queries and Mutations. It suppose to look like below:

pseudocode:

```
schema {
  query: UserQueries & EventQueries,
  mutation: UserMutations & EventMutations
}
```

So, how to concat queries and mutations between entities like pseudocode above shows? Is it a good way and a proper architecture?

I attach also .js code

```
const userSchema = addResolversToSchema({
  schema,
  resolvers: {
    UserMutations,
    UserQueries
  }
})
```

Comment: One way to go may be to introduce "namespaces", as described in the [GraphQL.NET documentation](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/query-organization). That is, you create a top-level `type` for queries which has the two fields `user: UserQueries` and `event: EventQueries`. But this would not concatenate the queries and would break existing clients.